# Mach vs Spring Operating Systems

Tags: operating-system, mach

I have to write a paper on an operating system topic. I decided to get some information about Mach and Spring (being both microkernel and object-oriented operating systems). I'd like the paper to be a comparison between some specific aspects about the two systems (a full comparison would be too large for a 6-7 page paper). Which aspects of the two systems can I compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring was designed as a post-Mach system, so any information you can find out about Spring from the Sun authors is very likely to (at least indirectly) provide comparisons to Mach. Some direct points of comparison:

- Spring's *domains* are analogous to Mach's *tasks*
- Spring's *nucleus* is directly comparable with the Mach 3 *kernel*, and the two provide different *virtual memory* managers
- Spring IPC uses *doors* (which made their way into the Solaris OS), which have different characteristics from Mach's *ports*
- IPC in both is abstracted behind an *Interface Definition Language*, and the two can be compared